# How to send nested structure using MPI_Datatype in MPI using C

Tags: c, distributed, mpi, distributed-computing

I am trying to use MPI_Datatype to send the below structure but the  MPI_Send crashes while sending the structure. I am wondering how to handle this situation. Here is the code I have written to define new MPI data-type:

```
   typedef struct
    {
       double x;
       double y;
    } vertex;

   typedef struct
   {
        int num_vertices;
        vertex vertex[2];
   } vertex_list;


       MPI_Datatype vertexType;
        MPI_Type_contiguous(2,MPI_DOUBLE,&vertexType);
        MPI_Type_commit(&vertexType);

      MPI_Datatype vertexListType;
        MPI_Datatype typev[3] = {MPI_INT, vertexType, MPI_UB};
        int blocklenv[3] = {1, 2, 1};
        MPI_Aint dispv[3];
        /* compute displacements of structure components */
        MPI_Address( vertexl, dispv);
        MPI_Address( vertexl[0].vertex, dispv+1);
        MPI_Address(  vertexl+1, dispv+2);
        base = dispv[0];

        for (i=0; i <3; i++)
         dispv[i] -= base;

        /* build datatype describing structure */
        MPI_Type_struct( 3, blocklenv, dispv, typev, &vertexListType);
        MPI_Type_commit(&vertexListType);
```

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OQFtx0ClkKQx7X91BlVgiizs5D9jShhtgsKafrgC7hk/edit?hl=en

Comment: You can edit your post rather than add comments. Code in the post proper can be nicely formatted and the question will be better all around.

Comment: I've copied in the code for you (just waiting for the peer review).  In the future, as `pmg` says, you can edit your own post and using the code formatting helps to get a quicker response.

Comment: You should show the send as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Captain @Head. how to MPI_Send in case of non-contiguous data in the nested structure for example when vertices is a pointer field :
                   typedef struct{
                    double x;
                    double y;
                   } vertex;

                   typedef struct
                   {
                    int num_vertices;
                    vertex *vertices;
                   } vertex_list;

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure your structs are going to work the way you're intending here, but I can share my experience with sending structs with MPI_Send.

Rather than creating an explicit MPI datatype it's possible to simply send the struct itself since all of its contents are in a contiguous piece of memory. The trick is providing the correct size and datatype for the MPI_Send operation.

Using your structs, here's what I've done in the past (assuming variable `vertex_list list` has already been defined):

```
MPI_Send(&list, sizeof(vertex_list), MPI_BYTE, <rankToSendTo>, <tagInteger>, <comm>);
```

So the data buffer to be sent is a pointer to the list struct, the size of the buffer is the size of a vertex_list in bytes and the MPI datatype is simply bytes.

On the receiving end, you just need to supply a vertex_list reference as the receiving buffer:

```
vertex_list receiveList;
MPI_Recv(&receiveList, sizeof(vertex_list), MPI_BYTE, <rankOfSender>, <tagInteger>, <comm>, <status>);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Head thanks for your reply. how to MPI_Send in case of non-contiguous data in the nested structure for example when vertices is a pointer field ie "vertex *vertex" instead of "vertex vertex[2]"

Comment: That certainly gets trickier because (I assume in this case) there is no simple way for the receiving process to know how many vertices are in the *vertex list.

Edit: Perhaps some more info on what you're attempting to do with those vertices on the receiving end might spark some ideas.