# How to send a struct inside another struct over mpi send

Tags: c, struct, mpi

If I have 2 structs,

```
struct {
   int a;
   int b;
} st_a;
```

and

```
struct {
  double c;
  st_a d;
} st_b;
```

Is there a way to send st_b using mpi_Send?

Comment: MPI type construction is recursive. So you can make a Struct or Contiguous type for `st_a`, and then a Struct type for `st_b`.

Answer (score -1):

You send the structure the same way. A structure is just contiguous bytes, and nested structures are no exception. According to the document https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Send.html, you just have to be carefull with the size, but that shouldn't be a problem, as you have several ways to get the `sizeof` what you want in C.


Also you might want to see this post :

[How to send nested structure using MPI_Datatype in MPI using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969864/how-to-send-nested-structure-using-mpi-datatype-in-mpi-using-c)